# Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' and get chunks on client problem

Tags: next.js

Lately I see this error in server console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of (0 , _path.join)
at Object.fn (/home/my-project/www/my-project/node_modules/next/next-server/server/next-server.ts:658:25)
at Router.execute (/home/my-project/www/my-project/node_modules/next/next-server/server/router.ts:346:40)
at Server.run (/home/my-project/www/my-project/node_modules/next/next-server/server/next-server.ts:1266:41)
at Server.requestHandler [as handleRequest] (/home/my-project/www/my-project/node_modules/next/next-server/server/next-server.ts:566:25)
at /home/my-project/www/my-project/node_modules/next/server/next.ts:50:14
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I don't understand what caused this and maybe it's due to some settings on aws, I'm just a developer, I don't know how to set up "there"

I also found this(on client side, when page loaded via SSR, i see it in console), maybe these are related problems with some settings on the server itself:

```
GET https://my-project.com/_next/static/chunks/pages/my-project-page/my-page-e8304b6d783911422987.js net::ERR_ABORTED 503
```